# Multiple Drop table statement in a query fails

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a temp table which needs to be recreated with different `where` conditions. Even though I have a drop statement for the temp table the query fails when executed, is there any way to overcome this issue. Please find the below example for better clarity. any help is much appreciated.

```
drop table if exists table1;

create table table1(id int)

insert into table1 values (2),(3)

drop table if exists #temp;

select * into #temp from(select * from table1 where id=2)a;

drop table if exists #temp;

select * into #temp from(select * from table1 where id=3)a;
```

Comment: seems you have not the create #temp ....

Comment: Sorry I could not understand

Comment: you have drop table  #temp;  .. but after this you have not  the create table #temp .. so the select must fail

Comment: I believe select * into statement creates a table in its own.

Comment: it should  anyway i  have posted  an answer with a different sintax hope i usefull

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this. It is good practice to use `GO` to make batches of your query.

```
drop table if exists table1;
go

create table table1(id int)

insert into table1 values (2),(3)
go

drop table if exists #temp;
go

select * into #temp from table1 where id=2;
go

drop table if exists #temp;
go

select * into #temp from table1 where id=3;
```

Comment: Thank you, separating as a batch is the key to handle this.